# Web api file size download limit

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I need to disallow both get and post not to allow file size more than 120 mb.
I am pretty sure that following entry in web.config disallow to post file size more than specified, however I am not sure if it applies to get as well?

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="120000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

To be more specific in case of Get:

If some one requests the api for a fileId 123 and the stored procedure retrieves the file but file size is larger than 120mb, then it should not send the file to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for restricting content download for a specific size limit (120 MB and above), then this setting is wrong, it controls only the request size (both get and post) not the response size, that you will have to handle by yourself.

the setting include the maximum size of a request, the maximum URL length, and the maximum length for a query string. so it is applicable to GET and POST as well. but its for the request size that your client sends to your server and not the response your client is downloading